# MySQL with RAD Studio XE2

Tags: mysql, delphi

I am using MYSQL server 5.5.15 with workbench installed

When i use RADPHP xe2 (update 2 ) with mysql(Using Data Explorer) it can connect correctly and i can start working with them easily.

But when using Delphi xe2(update 2 ) following error is shown

> Borland.Data.TDBXError: DBX Error:  Driver could not be properly initialized.  Client library may be missing, not installed properly, of the wrong version, or the driver may be missing from the system path.

when i checked the rad studio bin folder there is no any libmysql.dll (but found in radphp bin folder), so i copied there but still problem

Comment: why RADphp and Delphi are working differently

Comment: Do you have Enterprise version or above? I think the professional version can only connect to local databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a libmysql.dll from 5.1 server. It can be found here: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html

Comment: Or maybe MySQL support is implemented in a different way in php and delphi.

Comment: libmysql.dll from 5.1 server doesn't work with your Delphi? I don't remember wich version I tried myself, probably 5.1.54. Everything worked well.

Comment: Another possibility is connection via ODBC.

Comment: thanks , i think this is an acceptable answer ,i will accept this after clarifying , sorry i just confused with radphp but still i can't understand why radphphs  libmysql.dll working.

Comment: http://wiltonsoftware.com/posts/view/getting-embarcadero-dbexpress-mysql-working-dbx-error-driver-not-initialized is having only libmysql

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5549/discussion-between-vibeeshanrc-and-torbins)